# Triangular Arbitrage formula

Tags: research

i have 3 currencies AUD, USD and EU

I am trying to work out the mathematical formula to work out if there is a spread/arbitrage opportunity as well as the maximum amount that can be conducted ( for instance, if transferring from USD to EUR is limited by $100USD, then that is the limiting factor).

here is a wiki describing the transaction flow https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Triangular-arbitrage.svg

Comment: not sure why this is offtopic. triangular arbitrage formula/math is very hard to find on the web and is hard to wrap my head around.  I wouldnt say it is basic.